# Android Room Java Inner Join with Count

Tags: java, join, count, android-room

I'm writing an android app in java, using Room to manage the data.

I want to return all items in one database (contacts_table) with a corresponding count of related items from another table (emails_table) to use in a recycler view.

i.e. I want the user to see how many emails they have from a contact in each layout of the recycler view.

When I test run my app I get this error:

```
error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: emails_table)
```

at this line of code:

```
    @Query("SELECT  e.emails_count, c.* " +
            "FROM contacts_table c " +
            "INNER JOIN ( " +
            "   SELECT email_to, COUNT(email_to) emails_count " +
            "   FROM emails_table " +
            "   GROUP BY email_to) e " +
            "ON e.email_to = c.email_to")
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

**contacts_table entity:**

```
@Entity(tableName = "contacts_table")
public class ContactEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_token")
    private String emailToken;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_to")
    private String emailTo;

    private String password;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "contact_name")
    private String contactName;

    public ContactEntity(String emailToken, String password, String contactName) {
        this.emailToken = emailToken;
        this.password = password;
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getEmailToken() {
        return emailToken;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setEmailToken(String emailToken) {
        this.emailToken = emailToken;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }


    public String getEmailTo() {
        return emailTo;
    }

    public void setEmailTo(String emailTo) {
        this.emailTo = emailTo;
    }

}
```

**contacts_dao:**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface ContactsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insert(ContactEntity contactEntity);

    @Update
    void update(ContactEntity contactEntity);

    @Delete
    void delete(ContactEntity contactEntity);
//
    @Query("SELECT  e.emails_count, c.* " +
            "FROM contacts_table c " +
            "INNER JOIN ( " +
            "   SELECT email_to, COUNT(email_to) emails_count " +
            "   FROM emails_table " +
            "   GROUP BY email_to) e " +
            "ON e.email_to = c.email_to")
    LiveData<List<ContactEntity>> getAllContacts();

    @Query("DELETE FROM contacts_table")
    void deleteAllContacts();

}
```

**emails_table entity:**

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Time;

@Entity(tableName = "emails_table")
public class EmailEntity {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_from")
    private String emailFrom;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_to")
    private String emailTo;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_subject")
    private String emailSubject;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_body")
    private String emailBody;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_date")
    private Date dateReceived;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_time")
    private Time timeReceived;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_filename")
    private String filename;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_archive")
    private Boolean isArchived;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "email_token")
    private String emailToken;

    public EmailEntity(String emailFrom, String emailTo, String emailBody, Date dateReceived, Time timeReceived, String filename, Boolean isArchived, String emailSubject) {
        this.emailFrom = emailFrom;
        this.emailTo = emailTo;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
        this.dateReceived = dateReceived;
        this.timeReceived = timeReceived;
        this.filename = filename;
        this.isArchived = isArchived;
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmailFrom() {
        return emailFrom;
    }

    public void setEmailFrom(String emailFrom) {
        this.emailFrom = emailFrom;
    }

    public String getEmailTo() {
        return emailTo;
    }

    public void setEmailTo(String emailTo) {
        this.emailTo = emailTo;
    }

    public String getEmailBody() {
        return emailBody;
    }

    public void setEmailBody(String emailBody) {
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
    }

    public Date getDateReceived() {
        return dateReceived;
    }

    public void setDateReceived(Date dateReceived) {
        this.dateReceived = dateReceived;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public Boolean getArchived() {
        return isArchived;
    }

    public void setArchived(Boolean archived) {
        isArchived = archived;
    }

    public String getEmailToken() {
        return emailToken;
    }

    public void setEmailToken(String emailToken) {
        this.emailToken = emailToken;
    }

    public String getEmailSubject() {
        return emailSubject;
    }

    public void setEmailSubject(String emailSubject) {
        this.emailSubject = emailSubject;
    }


    public Time getTimeReceived() {
        return timeReceived;
    }

    public void setTimeReceived(Time timeReceived) {
        this.timeReceived = timeReceived;
    }
}
```

**EmailsDao:**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.OnConflictStrategy;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface EmailsDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insert(EmailEntity emailEntity);

    @Update
    void update(EmailEntity emailEntity);

    @Delete
    void delete(EmailEntity emailEntity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM emails_table ORDER BY email_date")
    LiveData<List<EmailEntity>> getAllEmails();

    @Query("DELETE FROM emails_table")
    void deleteAllEmails();

}
```

**EmailsDatabase**

```
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.TypeConverters;
import com.xxxxxxxxxx.email_token.ui.contacts.ContactEntity;
import com.xxxxxxxxxx.email_token.ui.contacts.ContactsDao;


@Database(entities = {EmailEntity.class, ContactEntity.class}, version = 3)
@TypeConverters({DateConverter.class, TimeConverter.class})
public abstract class EmailsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static EmailsDatabase instance;

    public abstract EmailsDao emailsDao();
    public abstract ContactsDao contactsDao();
    public abstract HeaderDao headerDao();

    public static synchronized EmailsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    EmailsDatabase.class, "emails_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is the stack-track from the Build Output:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project /home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/email_token

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest
> Task :app:processDebugResources

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
/home/xxx/AndroidStudioProjects/email_token/app/src/main/java/com/xxxxxxxxxx/email_token/ui/email_messages/ContactsDao.java:31: error: There is a problem with the query: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: emails_table)
    LiveData<List<ContactEntity>> getAllContacts();
                                  ^
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:106)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.execute(IncrementalResultStoringCompiler.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:154)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:122)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.kt:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    ... 35 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your code and running it using (without LiveData and type converters (String used instead of Date and Time types)) :-

```
emailsDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(this,EmailsDatabase.class,"emailsdb")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

        ContactEntity c1 = new ContactEntity("email1","password","Fred");
        c1.setEmailTo("email1");
        ContactEntity c2 = new ContactEntity("email2","password","Mary");
        c2.setEmailTo("email2");
        ContactEntity c3 = new ContactEntity("email3","password","Jane");
        c3.setEmailTo("email3");
        emailsDatabase.contactsDao().insert(c1);
        emailsDatabase.contactsDao().insert(c2);
        emailsDatabase.contactsDao().insert(c3);
        emailsDatabase.emailsDao().insert(
                new EmailEntity(
                        "email1",
                        "email2",
                        "Blah",
                        "2019-12-31",
                        "10:30","filex",
                        false,
                        "This")
        );
        emailsDatabase.emailsDao().insert(
                new EmailEntity(
                        "email1",
                        "email3",
                        "Blah",
                        "2019-12-31",
                        "10:30","filex",
                        false,
                        "This")
        );
        emailsDatabase.emailsDao().insert(
                new EmailEntity(
                        "email2",
                        "email1",
                        "Blah",
                        "2019-12-31",
                        "10:30","filex",
                        false,
                        "This")
        );
        emailsDatabase.emailsDao().insert(
                new EmailEntity(
                        "email1",
                        "email2",
                        "Blah",
                        "2019-12-31",
                        "10:40","filex",
                        false,
                        "This")
        );
        List<EmailEntity> emailEntityList = emailsDatabase.emailsDao().getAllEmails();
        for (EmailEntity e: emailEntityList) {
            logEmail(e);
        }
        List<ContactEntity> contactEntityList = emailsDatabase.contactsDao().getAllContacts();
        for (ContactEntity c: contactEntityList) {
            logContact(c);
        }
        List<ContactWithEmailCounts> contactWithEmailCountsList = emailsDatabase.contactsDao().testit();
        for (ContactWithEmailCounts cwec: contactWithEmailCountsList) {
            Log.d("CWECINFO","Email Count = " + cwec.emailcount);
        }
    }

    private void logEmail(EmailEntity e) {
        Log.d("EMAIlINFO","Email From = " + e.getEmailFrom() + "Email To " + e.getEmailTo() + "Email Token = " + e.getEmailToken());
    }
    private void logContact(ContactEntity c) {
        Log.d("CONTACTINFO","Name = " + c.getContactName() + " Email = " + c.getEmailToken());
    }
```

Along with a class :-

```
public class ContactWithEmailCounts {

    @Embedded
    ContactEntity contactEntity;
    int emailcount;
}
```

The Query being added to ContactsDao as (i.e. unchanged other than the method to be called which was added) :-

```
@Query("SELECT  e.emails_count AS emailcount, c.* " +
        "FROM contacts_table c " +
        "INNER JOIN ( " +
        "   SELECT email_to, COUNT(email_to) emails_count " +
        "   FROM emails_table " +
        "   GROUP BY email_to) e " +
        "ON e.email_to = c.email_to")
List<ContactWithEmailCounts> testit();
```

Then I get the following results (i.e  the @Query works rather than fails):-

> ```
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.439 D/EMAIlINFO: Email From = email1Email To email2Email Token = null
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.439 D/EMAIlINFO: Email From = email1Email To email3Email Token = null
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.439 D/EMAIlINFO: Email From = email2Email To email1Email Token = null
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.439 D/EMAIlINFO: Email From = email1Email To email2Email Token = null
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.440 D/CONTACTINFO: Name = Fred Email = email1
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.441 D/CONTACTINFO: Name = Mary Email = email2
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.441 D/CONTACTINFO: Name = Jane Email = email3
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.442 D/CWECINFO: Email Count = 1
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.442 D/CWECINFO: Email Count = 2
> 2020-01-11 20:36:37.442 D/CWECINFO: Email Count = 1
> ```

As such I suspect that the table not found is what exactly is, i.e. for some reason the table does not exist, perhaps it is with how you test run.

Comment: Hey Mike! Thanks for testing it and giving your feedback. My test is to run the app in the SDK's emulator, not very robust. Should I look more into how to run tests? This is my 'I want to learn how to write apps' project, first time writing in java, so sorry if my questions seem uneducated - it's because they are.

Comment: @RexB In short I can't see any fault with the code given, nor can I see how, under typical usage you would get such an error as Room would throw an exception if the table didn't exist or couldn't be created (I can't see any typo nor did using your code show one). It's as if the table has been dropped after room has built the database. So what I meant is that the issue appears to be elsewhere in the code run. First thing would be to add the stack-trace to the question rather just the single message from the stack-trace.

Comment: I've updated my question with the stacktrace output from the build process

Comment: @RexB try rebuild of project, also make sure you are using latest Room libs (just in case 2.2.3 I think).

Comment: My build.gradle(Module: app) file has this:<br/>
    `def room_version = "2.2.3"`<br/>
    `implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"`<br/>
    `annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"`<br/>

Comment: @RexB that's what my test used. So that's good. Did rebuild fix?

Comment: OMG I think it did! I can at least get the project to rebuild and run! That's so good. Thank you!

Comment: @RexB rule is if you pretty sure things are OK then rebuild. Great that it's worked.